# What is the difference between + and - when defining a property of method?

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, cocoa

and the - and + signs in front of a declaration of property and method confuses me a lot. Is there a difference if I declare the method this way:

```
- (void)methodName:(id)sender {}
```

and this way

```
+ (void)methodName:(id)sender {}
```

I really don't get it.

Comment: No offense but it sounds like you need to read a primer. Start here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html

Comment: I knew C, and other languages like Java, therefore I thought I don't have to because it may not be that much different.. I really should tho. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A '+' method is a class method, and can be called directly on the metaclass. It therefore has no access to instance variables.

A '-' method is an instance method, with full access to the relevant instance of the class.

E.g.

```
@interface SomeClass

+ (void)classMethod;
- (void)instanceMethod;

@property (nonatomic, assign) int someProperty;

@end
```

You can subsequently perform:

```
[SomeClass classMethod]; // called directly on the metaclass
```

Or:

```
SomeClass *someInstance = etc;

[someInstance instanceMethod]; // called on an instance of the class
```

Note that:

```
+ (void)classMethod
{
    NSLog(@"%d", self.someProperty); // this is impossible; someProperty belongs to
                                     // instances of the class and this is a class
                                     // method
}
```

Comment: So if I understand it properly, it can be compared to calling static methods in some extent. They don't have to be instantiated. What is the purpose of using them if they cannot access outside variables then, can you please explain? Thanks a lot for a rapid response..

Comment: @No One in Particular's answer explains what's their use. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't think this is the right usage of the term metaclass.http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/04/14/objc_explain_Classes_and_metaclasses.html

Comment: @Jon Hess: I think you're right; I've been very imprecise when trying to find a way to say, essentially, that class methods are to instance methods as metaclasses are to classes. That is, if you were to write the definition of a metaclass as an exercise, its instance methods would be class methods on the class it describes. Is that an accurate (if slightly confusing) description of the problem as you see it? If so I'll edit my comment appropriately; if not then how would you edit?

Answer (score 1):

To embelish on @Tommy's answer, the (-)methods will have the use of a 'self' variable which is the class instance that the method will work on.  The (+) methods won't have that.

For example, if you had a class FooBar and you wanted to compare 2 instances, you could do either of the following:

```
+ (BOOL) compare:(FooBar)fb1 and:(FooBar)fb2 {
        // compare fb1 and fb2
        // return YES or NO
}
```

or

```
- (BOOL) compare:(FooBar)fb2
        // compare self and fb2
        // return YES or NO
}
```

The second routine has the 'self' variable which is similar to the fb1 in the first routine.  (These routines are contrived, but I hope you get the picture.)

Comment: Class methods do also have a hidden `self` parameter, but it points to the class object rather than an instance.

Comment: Also, those parentheses surrounding `+` and `-` should surround the return type instead.

Comment: @Bavarious - thanks for the correction.  Already edited.  (I put this in on the fly.)

Comment: @Josh - you are correct, but I didn't want to muddy the waters when I thought the question was about instances themselves.  But thanks for keeping me on the straight and narrow.

Answer (score 1):

`- (void)methodName:(id)sender {}`

is an instance method, meaning you create an instance of a class, and can call the method on the object, or in Objective-C parlance, send a message to the object selector.

`+ (void)methodName:(id)sender {}`

is a class method, meaning it is a static method you call on the class itself, without first instantiating an object.

In the following example, `alloc` and `stringWithString` are class methods, which you call on the `NSString` class directly, no object required. On the other hand, `initWithString` is an instance method, which you call on the object returned by `[NSString alloc]`.

```
NSString* test = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"test"];

NSString* test2 = [NSString stringWithString:@"test2"];
```